# como envio 2 FormData() y como los recibo

Tags: php, jquery

estoy recibiendo 2 formularios por jquery y los quiero recibir por php

```
   $("#contactForm2").submit(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var parametro1= new FormData($("#contactForm")[0]);
    var parametros2= new FormData($("#contactForm2")[0]);
    parametros = parametro1+parametros2;
    //for (var i=0; i<1; i++) 
        const element = array[index];
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: "php/formulario_cliente.php",
            type: "post",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforesend: function(){
            },
            success: function(response){
                if(response != 'error'){
                    $("#subir_cliente").hide();
                    $('#mensaje_cliente').removeAttr('hidden');
                }else{
                    $("#subir_cliente").hide();
                    $('#mensaje_cliente').removeAttr('hidden');
                }
            }
        });
    //}
});

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","nuevo_usuario","contraseña","prueba2022");
$credito = $_POST['credito'];
$monto = $_POST['monto'];
$garantia = $_POST['garantia'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sector = $_POST['sector'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Verificamos con **isset** la llegada del *parametro*. No especificas que haces con los datos recibidos pero te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
<?php 
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","nuevo_usuario","contraseña","prueba2022");

if(isset($_POST['parametros'])){

  $credito = $_POST['credito'];
  $monto = $_POST['monto'];
  $garantia = $_POST['garantia'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $position = $_POST['position'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $sector = $_POST['sector'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];
  
  //Accion, consulta etc, que desees realizar aqui
  
  }else{
    echo "No recibi ningun dato";
  }
 }
?>
```